# Android Gradle how to change type of variable or argument in java file

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

How can i create a Gradle task to create a copy of my java source code and then look for specific classes and change them.

*example*: I want to change all variables,methods return type and methods arguments of type `com.a.*` to `java.lang.Object`, and then if possible comment all lines of code that has method call of Object (ex: java.lang.Object.methodName()).

original file:

```java
public final class MyClass {

    private com.a.ClassA varA_A;
    private com.a.ClassB varA_B;
    private com.b.ClassA varB_A;

    public Something(com.a.ClassA paramA_A, com.b.ClassA paramB_A, com.a.ClassB paramA_B) {
        //construct
    }

    public static final com.a.ClassB getInstance(com.a.ClassC paramA_C, com.b.ClassA paramB_A) {
        Object temp = null;
        if (1 == 1) {
            temp = com.a.ClassA.method(paramA_C);
        } else {
            temp = com.b.ClassB.method(paramA_C);
        }
        return (com.a.ClassB) temp;
    }

}
```

file that will be generated should look like this:

```java
public final class MyClass {

    private java.lang.Object varA_A;
    private java.lang.Object varA_B;
    private com.b.ClassA varB_A;

    public Something(java.lang.Object paramA_A, com.b.ClassA paramB_A, java.lang.Object paramA_B) {
        //construct
    }

    public static final java.lang.Object getInstance(java.lang.Object paramA_C, com.b.ClassA paramB_A) {
        Object temp = null;
        if (1 == 1) {
            temp = java.lang.Object.method(paramA_C);
        } else {
            temp = com.b.ClassB.method(paramA_C);
        }
        return (java.lang.Object) temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your use case here? Looks like its work of annotation processing or code generation & looking at your current approach Gradle doesn't provide specific role here.

Comment: I cannot change the java source code, so it has to be done with a Gradle task or plugin on a copy of the source code